# hive: how to handle scd type 2 without update

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, scd2

currently in our on-prem Hadoop environment we are using hive table with transaction properties. However as we have moving to AWS we don't have that feature yet. and so want to understand how to handle SCD Type 2 without updates.

for example.
for following record.

**With Updates**

[image]

In table with transaction properties enabled,  when I get an update for a record, I go ahead and change the `end_date` to `current date` and create new record with `effective_date` as `current date` and `end_date` as `12/31/9999`, as shows in above table.  And so it's easier to find my `active record` (where end_date = "12/31/9999").

However, if I can't update the past record. I have two records with same `end_date`. as shows in table below.

**My question are.**
if I can update `end_date` of past record,

1. How do I get the historical duration of stay?
2. How do i get active record?

**without updates**

[image]

Comment: You will need to rewrite the whole table, basically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, convert all dates to the `'yyyy-MM-dd'` format, so they all will be sortable and analytic functions will work. Then you can use `lead(effective_date, '2019-01-01') over(partition by id order by effective_date)`. For id=1 and effective_date = 2019-01-01 it should give you '2020-08-15' and you can assign this value as end_date for '2019-01-01' record. If there is no record with bigger effective_date, '9999-01-01' will be assigned. After this transformation Active record is that having '9999-01-01'.

Suppose dates are already converted to yyyy-MM-dd, this is how you can rewrite your table (after insert):

```
insert overwrite table your_table
select name, id, location, effective_date,  
       lead(effective_date,'2019-01-01') over(partition by id order by effective_date) as end_date 
 from your_table
```

Or without doing insert first, you can UNION ALL existing records with new records, in a subquery, then calculate lead.

Actually, SCD2 is not recommended for historical data rewriting because of non-equi join implementation in hive. It is implemented as cross-join + filter (or duplicating join on dim.id=fact.id (this will duplicate rows) + where fact.date<=dim.end_date and fact.date>=dim.effective_date - this should filter one record). This join is very expensive if the dimension and fact are big because of duplication before filtering.

Comment: wouldn't insert overwrite on huge table a performance issue. if scd type 2 is not recommended how do people maintain history of their dimension records?

Comment: @GaurangShah Usually they do not maintain SCD2. 1. Keeping tables denormalized with all dimension attributes. 2. Using SCD1.  Overwriting dimension is not the biggest problem which can happen in Hive. Joining of big fact with big dimension is a bigger performance problem. Non-equi-join is a bigger problem